# Installing Python packages via Bootstrap Actions for PySpark on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

I've got a problem that's driving me crazy partly because it's so simple.

So I have an ETL job I'd like to perform using pySpark on EMR. Problem is there are packages I need to install such as: numpy, py-stringmatching, etc. and I can't seem to pre-install the packages before running jobs.

This is where I am:

Setup ec2 instance, s3 buckets, successfully launched a Spark cluster using the UI on AWS. I've attempted to use the shell script below to install stuff via "bootstrap actions" then run the spark application through a "Step", scripts are below. They both live on S3 and I just have the cluster point to the directories.

**boostrap_actions.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

sudo pip install -U py-stringmatching
```

**check_numpy.py**

```
import numpy as np
```

... it fails on running check_numpy.py as a "step". Please lmk if you know anything about this or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi. Numpy should come pre-shipped on EMR to be honest. But that isnt the issue. That should run - do you wait until the cluster is in the 'Waiting/Ready' green state before you try that? What happens if you remove the check_numpy.py check, wait for cluster to get to green state, and then see what happens if you do that manually?

Comment: Steps only run once the cluster is in the ready state, so unfortunately that isn't the issue either. You are correct though that numpy is currently installed by default on EMR. What error do you get when you try to import numpy?

Comment: BTW, this isn't the issue either, but you might want to see if the AmazonLinux yum repo has this package rather than installing it with pip. The version you'd get from the AmazonLinux repo (if it's there) will be pre-compiled, whereas I think the one you'd get by installing it with pip will probably have to be compiled from source, which may take slightly longer. It might not matter that much for smaller packages, but for certain ones (like numpy, actually) take a very long time to compile from source.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I'm still struggling with installing Python packages on EMR (specifically, Pandas). I've tried just about everything I can think of.

Comment: This is a very old post but may be this will help https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2018/08/11/setup-spark-cluster-on-aws-emr/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bootstrap the cluster with a .sh file :

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

It worked for me!

But I made sure to see what the cluster was using with `which python` and `which pip` on master.